# Android PercentRelativeLayout doesn´t appear in RecyclerView

Tags: android

I think the problem is, that the Recycler doesn´t have a height. So my Percent-Layout can´t fill a height of '0' with 100%
How to get a height of every child of the RecyclerView?

Content of the Recycler (the percentLayout):

```
    <android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:background="#000000">

    <TextView
        app:layout_widthPercent="5%"
        app:layout_heightPercent="100%"
        app:layout_marginTopPercent="5%"
        app:layout_marginLeftPercent="2%"
        app:layout_marginRightPercent="75%"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="Medium Text"
        android:id="@+id/txt_roomname_map"

        android:background="#3c64f6"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"

        />
    <TextView
        app:layout_widthPercent="35%"
        app:layout_heightPercent="100%"
        app:layout_marginTopPercent="5%"
        app:layout_marginLeftPercent="13%"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="Medium Text"
        android:id="@+id/txt_weapons_in_room_map"
        android:background="#3c64f6"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"

    />

    <TextView
        app:layout_widthPercent="35%"
        app:layout_heightPercent="100%"
        app:layout_marginTopPercent="5%"
        app:layout_marginLeftPercent="52%"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="Medium Text"
        android:id="@+id/txt_weapons_in_room_map2"
        android:background="#3c64f6"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"/>

    <TextView
        app:layout_widthPercent="5%"
        app:layout_heightPercent="100%"
        app:layout_marginTopPercent="5%"
        app:layout_marginLeftPercent="93%"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="Medium Text"
        android:id="@+id/txt_roomname_map2"
        android:background="#3c64f6"
        android:textColor="#ffffff" />
</android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout>
```

The RecyclerLayout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:background="#000000">



    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/recyclerview"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageView3"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:id="@+id/imageView3"

        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Could anybody help me?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot set the height of your PercentRelativeLayout as a percent of the screen, because you cannot get access to the height of a RecyclerView from the layout item.

But you can set the width to 100% and use layout_aspectRatio.